# Simple Android studio NavigationDrawer Activity toggle Button is false

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I using Android studio version 1.2.2 the latest right now and my minsdkversion is api 8. when I create a new project with simple NavigationDrawer Activity with wizard it has a problem.
for toggle button icon app shows a "back icon" instead of "ic_drawer" that is in code that creates by itself.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) { ...
```

Please just create a simple NavigationDrawer Activity in Android Studio and say the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do my job when I am writing question but I continued, maybe this topic be helpful for someone.
I can say Android studio have a bug in this. I used Eclipse Luna for creating Navigation Drawer activity and now with comparing this two code can know where is the problem. maybe I understand the problem soon and I will post it here.

EDIT: just using `appcompat-v7:21.0.3` instead of appcompat-v7:22.1.1 fixed the problem.